# Execution PowerShell scrript inside Windows 10 based Vagrant machine

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I have PowerShell script which installs .exe file and need to be execute in Windows 10 virtual machine operated by Vagrant.

I am able to do this if I log in by using GUI of VirtualBox and run script manually.

I have tried:

`vagrant powershell -c ".\script.ps1"`

`vagrant powershell -c "C:\vagrant\script.ps1 | Invoke-Item"`

Also I have tried to execute PowerShell script by .cmd file

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%I_.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Here is response from Vagrant in PowerShell

```
==> default: Command: Invoke-Item C:\vagrant\I_O.ps1 executed succesfully with output code 0.
```

But nothing actually happen. Task Manager doesn't contain any process which is relate to .exe which I need to execute.

Comment: If you run `vagrant powershell` you should get an interactive PS prompt?

Comment: @JamesC. After I executed this cmdlet it stuck

`PS C:\VB\Win10> vagrant powershell
==> default: Detecting if a remote PowerShell connection can be made with the guest...
    default: Creating powershell session to 127.0.0.1:55985
    default: Username: vagrant`

Comment: OK, so WinRM is working and vagrant can connect to the machine. Your script "C:\vagrant\script.ps1" is present on the vagrant machine? (you've copied to the vagrant machine during provisioning?)

Comment: @JamesC. I have tried same vagrant powershell not with PS ISE but with PS and now I am authorized. Yes, script is present on the Vagrant machine.

Comment: @JamesC. I can't understand why I am able to run the script manually but I can't do this with any known PS cmdlet through 'vagrant powershell'?

I can install certificate, install chocolatey and set execution policy in Vagrant machine but I can't execute one last script.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's the problem - Windows (at least Windows 10) can't run application which I need if user is not logged in.

I didn't find how to manage authorization in Windows GUI with Vagrant, so I used this PowerShell script for autologon:

```
$winLogging ='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion \Winlogon'
New-ItemProperty -Path $winLogging -Name AutoAdminLogon -PropertyType String -Value 1 -force | Out-Null    
New-ItemProperty -Path $winLogging -Name DefaultUserName -PropertyType String -Value Vagrant -force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path $winLogging -Name DefaultPassword -PropertyType String -Value vagrant -force | Out-Null
```

And executed it inside virtual machine.

After that I ran:

```
vagrant reload
```

And after PowerShell script for installation of .exe file executed successfully.